# WindowBuilder: no carga los elementos de la ventana

Tags: java, windowbuilder

Estoy creando una ventana básica (un formulario para registro) en WindowBuilder.

Dentro de mi proyecto tengo dos clases:

- Principal.java, que es desde donde creo el objeto de la ventana y desde donde se debe ejecutar, llamando al objeto desde el método main.
- Ventana.java, donde está definida la ventana y todos sus elementos.

Cuando ejecuto Ventana.java se carga ésta y todos sus elementos, sin problemas. Cuando ejecuto Principal.java me crea la ventana, pero no me carga los elementos.
No sé si es por algo de la configuración del eclipse o porque se me haya pasado algo por alto.
¡Gracias[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he conseguido solucionar.
En el método main he tenido que meter la siguiente línea de código.

```
Ventana ventana = new Ventana(); //para crear la ventana que tengo en la clase Ventana.java
ventana.setVisible(true); //invocando este método "setVisible(true)" ya me carga la ventana con todos los elementos.
```